# Spring Executorservice Error-Handling

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, exception, executorservice

I implemented the Spring-TaskExecutor (which is the equivalent of the JDK 1.5's Executor.) to process notifications notifications receiving from external systems.

Interface with only one method:

```
 public interface AsynchronousService {
    void executeAsynchronously(Runnable task);
}
```

and the corresponding implementation:

```
public class AsynchronousServiceImpl implements AsynchronousService {

    private TaskExecutor taskExecutor;

    @Override
    public void executeAsynchronously(Runnable task) {
        taskExecutor.execute(task);
    }

    @Required
    public void setTaskExecutor(TaskExecutor taskExecutor) {
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
    }
}
```

Xml-configuration of the task executor (legacy application):

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.example.impl.NotificationPool">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1"/>
        <property name="queueCapacity" value="100"/>
        <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

1 is set for both, corePoolSize and maxPoolSize, since I want the tasks to execute sequentially (only 1 thread is created by the pool which process the tasks).

I want to order my task based on the date when i received the notification, therefore I  need to override this function to allow priority ordering:

```
public class NotificationPool extends ThreadPoolTaskExecutor {
     @Override
     protected BlockingQueue<Runnable> createQueue(int queueCapacity) {
          return new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(queueCapacity);
        }
    }
```

Here is the Notification task class:

```
public class NotificationTask implements Runnable, Comparable<NotificationTask> {

    private final NotificationService notificationService;
    private final Notification notification;

    public NotificationService(NotificationService notificationService, 
                               Notification notification) {
        this.notificationService = notificationService;
        this.notification = notification;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(NotificationTask task) {
        return notification.getTimestamp().compareTo(task.getTimestamp());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        notificationService.processNotification(notification);
    }
}
```

And this is how I execute it:

```
asynchronousService.executeAsynchronously(new NotificationTask (notificationService, notification));
```

Now, what if something goes wrong or how do you even know something gone wrong? For example if one of the tasks throws an exception? How do you handle that? I would like to log if exceptions are thrown.

I found an article (https://ewirch.github.io/2013/12/a-executor-is-not-a-thread.html) which suggests to override `afterExecute()` - method of the class: `ThreadPoolExecutor`. However, I'm currently using Spring's `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` which doesn't have the `beforeExecute()` and `afterExecute()` callback method of Java's `ThreadPoolExecutor`.

I could extend the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor` and override the `initializeExecutor()` method and create an instance of my custom `ThreadPoolExecutor`. But the problem is that the `initializeExecutor` method uses private fields of the `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`.

Does someone has a better idea or a better approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/scheduling/concurrent/ThreadPoolTaskExecutor.html) said that

> For an alternative, **you may set up a ThreadPoolExecutor instance directly using constructor injection**, or use a factory method definition that points to the Executors class. To expose such a raw Executor as a Spring TaskExecutor, simply wrap it with a ConcurrentTaskExecutor adapter.

But I didn't see any constructor related to `ThreadPoolExecutor` where we can inject, so it's probably a myth or they alrady removed the feature.

Fortunately we have `ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean` to rescue:

> If you prefer native ExecutorService exposure instead, consider ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean as an alternative to this class.

This executor expose a method which we can customize the threadpool:

```
public class NotificationPool extends ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean {
     @Override
     protected BlockingQueue<Runnable> createQueue(int queueCapacity) {
          return new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(queueCapacity);
     }

     @Override
     protected ThreadPoolExecutor createExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maxPoolSize, int keepAliveSeconds, BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue, ThreadFactory threadFactory, RejectedExecutionHandler rejectedExecutionHandler) {
        return new YourCustomThreadPoolExecutor(corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue, threadFactory, rejectedExecutionHandler);
     }
}
```

And override the default `afterExecute` callback:

```
public class YourCustomThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    public YourCustomThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, ThreadFactory threadFactory, RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory, handler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
        // Here do something with your exception
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx very much for your answer. Sry for applying so late. But the problem is that you cannot convert ThreadPoolExecutor to the TaskExecutor. `Failed to convert property value of type 'org.example.YourCustomThreadPoolExecutor  to required type 'org.example.task.TaskExecutor'`

Comment: I think I need to wire it up  somehow with the `TaskExecutorAdapter ` instead of `TaskExecutor`, however I did not manage to get it work so far

Comment: Then change the method to return Executor (or ExecutorService) depend on your need

Comment: But i need to use the `ThreadPoolExecutor`, or what do you exactly mean?

Comment: Make 3 changes to your current code: 1. Create YourCustomThreadPoolExecutor to handle exception. 2. Change NotificationPool to accept YourCustomThreadPoolExecutor. 3. Refer your executor as Executor instead of TaskExecutor

Comment: Yeah I already did all that, but I had another different spring error which was not related to that at all, that's why I got confused at the beginning :-). But your solution works, thx very much

Comment: BTW: I just need too check if the Throwable object is not null correct? :
    `@Override
    protected void afterExecute(final Runnable r, final Throwable t) {
        if (t != null)      {
            //Log exception
        }`

Comment: I think so, since you don't always get exception from your executor

Comment: I am trying to make my implementation more reliable, that's why I am trying to persist a task. I posted my idea how I can do it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51022412/java-executorservice-persist-queue   
I would be happy if you could check it

Answer (score 0):

You can easly use like this.

```
ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor() {
        @Override
        public void execute(@NotNull Runnable task) {
            try {
                super.execute(task);
            } catch (Throwable e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            }
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use formal Spring Async mechanism.

```
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class AsyncConfiguration implements AsyncConfigurer {

   @Bean("taskExecutor")
public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
    return new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
}

@Override
public AsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler getAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    return new SimpleAsyncUncaughtExceptionHandler(); // U can customize
}
```

Usage:

```
public class BlaBla {

@Async("taskExecutor")
public void doSomething() {
   ...
   }
}
```