# java executorservice persist queue

Tags: java, spring, persistence, executorservice

I implemented the Spring-TaskExecutor (which is the equivalent of the JDK 1.5's Executor.) to process notifications notifications receiving from external systems.

Interface with only one method:

```
 public interface AsynchronousService {
    void executeAsynchronously(Runnable task);
}
```

and the corresponding implementation:

```
public class AsynchronousServiceImpl implements AsynchronousService {

    private Executor taskExecutor;

    @Override
    public void executeAsynchronously(Runnable task) {
        taskExecutor.execute(task);
    }

    @Required
    public void setTaskExecutor(Executor taskExecutor) {
        this.taskExecutor = taskExecutor;
    }
}
```

Xml-configuration of the task executor (legacy application):

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.example.impl.NotificationPool">
        <property name="corePoolSize" value="1"/>
        <property name="maxPoolSize" value="1"/>
        <property name="queueCapacity" value="100"/>
        <property name="WaitForTasksToCompleteOnShutdown" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

1 is set for both, corePoolSize and maxPoolSize, since I want the tasks to execute sequentially (only 1 thread is created by the pool which process the tasks).

I want to order my task based on the date when i received the notification, therefore I  need to override this function to allow priority ordering:

```
public class NotificationPool extends ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean{
     @Override
     protected BlockingQueue<Runnable> createQueue(int queueCapacity) {
          return new PriorityBlockingQueue<>(queueCapacity);
        }
    }
```

The ThreadPoolExecutorFactoryBean exposes the ´createExecutor´ method, which I did override to create our own Executor:

```
@Override
protected ThreadPoolExecutor createExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maxPoolSize, int keepAliveSeconds,
                                            BlockingQueue<Runnable> queue, ThreadFactory threadFactory,
                                            RejectedExecutionHandler rejectedExecutionHandler) {
    return new YourCustomThreadPoolExecutor (corePoolSize, maxPoolSize, keepAliveSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS, queue,
            threadFactory, rejectedExecutionHandler);
```

Now, in my custom thread pool executor I can override the default afterExecute callback:

```
public class YourCustomThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    public YourCustomThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, ThreadFactory threadFactory, RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory, handler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);
        // Here do something with your exception
    }
}
```

Here is the Notification task class:

```
public class NotificationTask implements Runnable, Comparable<NotificationTask> {

    private final NotificationService notificationService;
    private final Notification notification;

    public NotificationService(NotificationService notificationService, 
                               Notification notification) {
        this.notificationService = notificationService;
        this.notification = notification;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(NotificationTask task) {
        return notification.getTimestamp().compareTo(task.getTimestamp());
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        notificationService.processNotification(notification);
    }
}
```

And this is how I execute it:

```
asynchronousService.executeAsynchronously(new NotificationTask (notificationService, notification));
```

I don't want only to have the queue in the memory but also persist the tasks in the database, so I have them even if the application crashes.

My first solution which come to my mind is to override the default `beforeExecute` callback in the `YourCustomThreadPoolExecutor` class:

```
public class YourCustomThreadPoolExecutor extends ThreadPoolExecutor {

    public YourCustomThreadPoolExecutor(int corePoolSize, int maximumPoolSize, long keepAliveTime, TimeUnit unit, BlockingQueue<Runnable> workQueue, ThreadFactory threadFactory, RejectedExecutionHandler handler) {
        super(corePoolSize, maximumPoolSize, keepAliveTime, unit, workQueue, threadFactory, handler);
    }

@Override
protected void beforeExecute(Thread t, Runnable r) {
    // 1) serialize runnable object
    // 2) write in the database (with a flag if it is executed true/false)  
    super.beforeExecute(t, r);
}

    @Override
    protected void afterExecute(Runnable r, Throwable t) {
        super.afterExecute(r, t);

    }
}
```

The idea is now, when I execute the task, I will check the database first, if it exists a task which is not executed (by checking a boolean flag for example). If yes, then I get this task first and execute it and update the flag. Then I continue executing the other task. So in this case, if the application crashes after executing a task, then I still make sure to execute this task after my application runs again, it doesn't get lost. What do you think of this solution?

First I tried to find a hook-method which is called before putting the tasks in the queue, so I can do the presistence of the tasks there. (Because I would prefer peristing the tasks before putting them in the queue) But I didn't find any way to do it, that's why my only chance is to override the `beforeExecutue` method. This is of course not so ideal, since I only start persisting the tasks when I dequeu them, so if the application crashes all my tasks in the queue are lost.

Comment: If you want persist then save your task before inserting into Queue

Comment: @Mạnh Quyết Nguyễn

Well I want to achieve that, but all the logic is handeld by the ExecutorService. I thought that I can modify the ExecutorService to do that, maybe there is a hook-method which I can override, however I cannot find any. But then I just persist the queue before calling: 

`asynchronousService.executeAsynchronously(new NotificationTask (notificationService, notification));`

This is what you meant?

Comment: Hi @Norbert94, did you make it work ? I'm interested in developing something similar, I think that your feedback would be quite helpful. Thanks in advance!

Comment: About persisting all queued task; what if you created a wrapper that delegates the tasks to the executor but persists them right before submitting ? You could also check whether a task is rejected to undo the persistence. What do you think ?

Comment: Hi @Ariles, I am sry to answer so late, yeah I made it work - I used this solution: http://carinae.net/2010/05/execution-persistent-transactional-tasks-with-spring/

I hope this helps you

Comment: @Norbert94 No worries. Thank you very much for the link !

Comment: @Ariles Did you use the same approach as descirbed in the link or did you use your own solution? if that's the case, it would be nice if you could share your own solution, so we can compare and discuss about the pros/cons

Comment: @Norbert94 What made sense "in my situation" is creating a periodic task. Its responsibility is to read data form the database to create sorted tasks accordingly and then submit them to the ExecutorService. Then, in my application, various objects can create tasks by simply writing to the database. The SingleThreadExecutor should avoid concurrency problems. And the PriorityBlockingQueue allows executing a few task in high priority.